# How to reload visualisation_canvas without exit prolog shell?

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [KnowRob_basics](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Tutorial:_KnowRob_basics).

I found when I run

```
  visualisation_canvas(C).
```

I only can run it once.

if I run again, it just shows:

```
  ?- visualisation_canvas(C).
  C = @'J#00000140499119889776'.
  
  ?-
```

How to call visualisation_canvas again without restart prolog?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40744/how-to-reload-visualisation_canvas-without-exit-prolog-shell?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, there is a way to kill the old canvas and start a new one, but it's a bit hacky (which does not have to be bad, though...)

visualisation_canvas(*).

retractall(mod_vis:v_canvas(*)), assert(mod_vis:v_canvas(fail)).
visualisation_canvas(_).

cheers
moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-08**:
Thank you~~ In my case I should run: retractall(mod_vis:v_canvas(C)), assert(mod_vis:v_canvas(fail)).
visualisation_canvas(C). It works!!